# C++! How are destructors called

Tags: c++, pointers

so i'm new to C++ (with java as a background) and i was going through `copy constructor` and `destructor` section but i still don't get it. The example i will show you is taken from tutorialpoints.com. So i have this code but the output just confuses me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line
{
   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

   private:
      int *ptr;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len)
{
    cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
    // allocate memory for the pointer;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
    ptr = new int;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void)
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    delete ptr;
}
int Line::getLength( void )
{
    return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( )
{
   Line line1(10);  //Line 1***************************

   Line line2 = line1; // This also calls copy constructor

   display(line1);
   display(line2);

   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

So in line 1 (Main), why does it also call the copy constructor when it has its own argument?
Also after the first call to the method `display` why is there another call to the `copy constructor` ? 

 this is the input i would have expected

```
`Normal constructor allocating ptr //Because Line one has its argument
Copy constructor allocating ptr.  //Because Line2 is a copy of Line1
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!  // Call to destructor after Line1 is desplayed
// Memory leak Since Line2 is now pointing to nothing, i guess is what we call `shallow pointers?!`
```

Sorry if it was too long, hopefully i was clear. PS i'm Only familiar with regular pointers!

Comment: Simplify your test code `main` until you really narrow down which lines belong to which statement. You're doing too much at once.

Comment: i also need to understand why which belongs to which!

Comment: I guess to answer your question in the title - the destructor is called when an object goes out of scope. [See here for an example](https://ideone.com/pL8ag9).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's confusing you is that `display` takes a `Line` by value. When you pass a `Line` to the `display` function, it copies it (calls copy ctor) into its local argument and when the `display` function ends, that local argument goes out of scope and the copied `Line` destructs.

```
int main( )
{
   Line line1(10);  // calls ctor that takes an int

   Line line2 = line1; // calls copy ctor

   display(line1); // calls copy ctor, prints, and then destructs the copy
   display(line2); // calls copy ctor, prints, and then destructs the copy

   return 0;
} // line 2 goes out of scope and destructs, then line 1 does the same
```

Comment: Spot on!!!! thanks so much but one thing i also don't get is that Since `line2` and `line1` point to the same location, how are they destruct twice? if you know what i mean

Comment: @Bobby they don't point to the same location. `line2` allocates some new memory and copies the contents from what `line1.ptr` points to into its own allocation. This is done in the copy ctor. If it did what you just described, it would read `ptr = obj.ptr;` in the copy ctor, and `line1` and `line2` would both point to the same thing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so this was a deep copy then!!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler emits code that automatically calls the destructor when an object is explicitly destroyed (e.g.  `delete` on an object created with operator `new`) or reaches the end of its defined life (e.g. a temporary destroyed when no longer needed, a declared variable passing out of scope).

In your code (as you have it at the time of my writing this) the sequence of events is

- `line1` is constructed
- `line2` is constructed as a copy of `line1`
- `line1` is passed by value to `display()`.   This creates a temporary
  copy of `line1`.  When `display()` returns, the destructor is invoked for the temporary.
- `line2` is passed by value to `display()`.   This creates a temporary
  copy of `line2`.  When `display()` returns, the destructor is invoked
  for the temporary.
- `main()` returns.
- `line1` and `line2` are destructed in reverse order of their
  construction, and destructor invoked for each.

Comment: Thank you a lot! this really helped my understanding as well. Didn't know about the `temporary` copy!

Answer (score 0):

> So in line 1 (Main), why does it also call the copy constructor when
>   it has its own argument?

It will not call copy constructor, comment your code in main  and try.
**live_demo:** http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64ad2d47a7ee953b

> Also after the first call to the method display why is there another
>   call to the copy constructor ?

```
void display(Line obj)
```

When you invoke this function since your passing argument by value system creates a local copy of object named `obj` to function, it is happening using copy constructor of your class. This local objects scope will end as soon execution completes the scope of your function `display`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is each part of main along with what it prints.

Line line1(10);  //Line 1***************************

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
```

Line line2 = line1; // This also calls copy constructor

```
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
```

display(line1);

```
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
```

display(line2);

```
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
```

return 0;
}

```
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

You are passing in `Line` by value so it copies the `Line` you have, calls the function and then the end of that function deletes the `Line` it got.